# Erlang c-nodes crashed randomly with double free, memory corruption malloc messege

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, erlang

I have an application running on otp-19.0, where there is a single erlang node and two c-nodes; several processes from erlang node continuously send messages to the c-node servers. The c-node accepts a single connection and process all the received messages (ERL_MSG-> ERL_REG_SEND, ERL_SEND) in separate threads except ERL_TICK, ERL_ERROR etc.

So in the c-node main() a connection is accepted and all the messages are received (erl_receive_msg), if the message is ERL_TICK, ERL_ERROR etc. they are dealt appropriately by freeing the memory, else if the message is ERL_MSG then a thread is created and the message is passed to the thread where it is processed and a reply is send using erl_send; this approach of handling message through thread is taken as some of the operation performed by the c-node takes considerable amount of time which is more than the tick time (is there a better way to do this?).

Now out of the two c-nodes one is crashing randomly (10 times in 24Hrs, more or less); both the c-nodes follows same architecture, only the operations they perform are different. In most of the times the c-node just goes down without giving any error reason and in 2 or 3 cases it crashes because of double free or memory corruption printer by malloc, the backtrace points to erl_receive_msg.

Another point observed is that, in the thread after erl_free_compound, when we look at the allocated blocks using erl_eterm_statistics(allocated, freed), it is 0 most of the times but sometimes it is non zero value, i.e. 9, 18, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Greg

Here is the main()

```
#include "error_code.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "erl_interface.h"
#include "ei.h"

#include "i2c_cnode.h"
#include "i2c_cnode_query_handler.h"

static int setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(char *node_name_without_ip,
    char *ip_address, char *magic_cookie, int socket_port_number);
static int initialize_socket_connection(int socket_port_number, int *socket_file_descriptor_return);
static int convert_string_to_integer(char *string_to_convert_into_integer, int *integer_value_return);    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *node_name_without_ip                      = NULL;
    char *ip_address_of_card                        = NULL;
    char *magic_cookie                          = NULL;

    int socket_port_number                          = 0;
    int socket_port_number_return                       = 0;
    int status_of_get_socket_port_number                    = FAILURE;

    int semaphore_count                         = 0;
    int semaphore_count_return                      = 0;
    int status_of_get_semaphore_count                   = FAILURE;

    int i = 0; /* used as a loop variable for creation of semaphore */
    int status_of_semaphore_creation                    = FAILURE;
    int socket_file_descriptor                      = 0;
    unsigned char erlang_message_buffer[ERLANG_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE]     = {0};
    int return_status_of_erl_receive_msg                    = ERL_ERROR;
    int return_status_of_erl_close_connection               = 0;

    ErlMessage *erlmessage                          = NULL;
    ErlConnect erlang_node_connection_information               = {
        .ipadr = {0},
        .nodename = {0}
    };
    pthread_t query_handler_thread_id;

    void release_all_eterm_resources()
    {
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->msg);
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->from);
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->to);

        erl_eterm_release();
        free(erlmessage);
    }

    if(NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGS != argc)
    {
        printf("\nError: Arguments validation from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n"
            "Usage : <executable_name> <node_name_without_ip> <ip_address> <cookie> <socket_port_number> <semaphore_count>\n"
            "For example : %s i2c_cnode 10.3.31.127 utl 4022 1 \n"
            "Terminating C node\n\n", __func__, __LINE__, argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    node_name_without_ip = argv[1];

    ip_address_of_card = argv[2];
    magic_cookie = argv[3];

    status_of_get_socket_port_number = convert_string_to_integer(argv[4], &socket_port_number_return);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_socket_port_number)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get Socket port number from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    socket_port_number = socket_port_number_return;

    status_of_get_semaphore_count = convert_string_to_integer(argv[5], &semaphore_count_return);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_semaphore_count)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get Semaphore count from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    semaphore_count = semaphore_count_return;

    if(MAX_COUNT_OF_SEMAPHORE_FOR_I2C_ACCESS < semaphore_count)
    {
        printf("\nError: Too may Semaphores requested from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    socket_file_descriptor = setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(
        node_name_without_ip, ip_address_of_card, magic_cookie, socket_port_number);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT_OF_SEMAPHORE_FOR_I2C_ACCESS; i++)
    {
        status_of_semaphore_creation = sem_init(&i2c_access_semaphore[i], 0, 1);
        if(FAILURE == status_of_semaphore_creation)
        {
            printf("\nError: Create POSIX semaphore from "
                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    while(1)
    {
        erlang_node_file_descriptor = erl_accept(socket_file_descriptor, &erlang_node_connection_information);
        if(ERL_ERROR == erlang_node_file_descriptor)
        {
            printf("\nError: Accepting connection from peer node from "
                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
            continue;
        }    

        while(1)
        {
            erlmessage = malloc(sizeof(ErlMessage));
            if(NULL == erlmessage)
            {
                printf("\nError: Get heap space for ErlMessage from "
                    __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }    

            return_status_of_erl_receive_msg = erl_receive_msg(erlang_node_file_descriptor,
                erlang_message_buffer,
                ERLANG_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE,
                erlmessage);    

            if(ERL_TICK == return_status_of_erl_receive_msg)
            {
                release_all_eterm_resources();
                continue;
            }    

            else if(ERL_ERROR == return_status_of_erl_receive_msg)
            {
                printf("\nError: Message receiving from the Erlang node %s, from "
                    __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                    erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                    __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));

                release_all_eterm_resources();
                if(EIO == erl_errno)
                {
                    return_status_of_erl_close_connection = erl_close_connection(
                        erlang_node_file_descriptor);
                    if(SUCCESS != return_status_of_erl_close_connection)
                    {
                        printf("\nError: Closing Erlang file descriptor from "
                            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if((ENOMEM == erl_errno) || (EMSGSIZE == erl_errno))
                {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                switch(erlmessage->type)
                {
                    case ERL_REG_SEND:
                    case ERL_SEND:

                        pthread_create(&query_handler_thread_id, NULL, query_handler, erlmessage);
                        break;

                    case ERL_EXIT:
                        printf("\nError: Message receive from the Erlang node %s, from "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));

                        printf("Received a ERL_EXIT with message: ");
                        erl_print_term(stdout, erlmessage->msg);
                        printf("\n");

                        return_status_of_erl_close_connection = erl_close_connection(erlang_node_file_descriptor);
                        if(SUCCESS != return_status_of_erl_close_connection)
                        {
                            printf("\nError: Close Erlang file descriptor from "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        }
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    case ERL_LINK:
                        printf("\nError : Link Message received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    case ERL_UNLINK:
                        printf("\nError : Unlink Message received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    default:
                        printf("\nError : Unknown Message type received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}    

static int setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(char *node_name_without_ip,
    char *ip_address, char *magic_cookie, int socket_port_number)
{
    char long_node_name_with_ip[MAX_BYTES_OF_FULL_NODE_NAME]    = {0};
    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX]                    = {0};

    struct in_addr ipv4_address_as_binary_data          = {0};

    int socket_file_descriptor                  = 0;
    int return_status_of_gethostname                = 0;
    int return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit              = 0;
    int return_status_of_erl_publish                = 0;
    int status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor            = FAILURE;    

    erl_init(NULL, 0);    

    return_status_of_gethostname = gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    if(FAILURE == return_status_of_gethostname)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get hostname from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sprintf(long_node_name_with_ip, "%s@%s", node_name_without_ip, ip_address);    

    ipv4_address_as_binary_data.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
    if(BROADCAST_IP_ADDRESS == ipv4_address_as_binary_data.s_addr)
    {
        printf("\nError: Convert of IPv4 dotted notation to binary data from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit = erl_connect_xinit(hostname,node_name_without_ip,
        long_node_name_with_ip, &ipv4_address_as_binary_data, magic_cookie, 0);
    if(return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit <= FAILURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Initialize C Node connection from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor = initialize_socket_connection(socket_port_number,
        &socket_file_descriptor);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor)
    {
        printf("\nError: Initialize socket connection from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    return_status_of_erl_publish = erl_publish(socket_port_number);
    if(FAILURE == return_status_of_erl_publish)
    {
        printf("\nError: Publish C node to EPMD from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nC Node name: %s\n", erl_thisnodename());    
    return socket_file_descriptor;
}

static int initialize_socket_connection(int socket_port_number, int *socket_file_descriptor_return)
{
    int socket_file_descriptor      = 0;
    int boolean_option          = 0;

    int setsockopt_return_status        = 0;
    int bind_return_status          = 0;
    int listen_return_status        = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in socket_address   = {0};    
    boolean_option = BOOLEAN_OPTION_ENABLE;

    /**
     * A socket is an endpoint for communication. socket() creates a socket according to the
     * IPV4 protocol(AF_INET)  which provides a sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based
     * byte streams(SOCK_STREAM) for communication between two entities. After creation, the
     * socket() returns a descriptor with respect to which further operations can be performed
     */
    socket_file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    if (FAILURE == socket_file_descriptor)
    {
        printf("\nError : Creation of socket from %s() failed with error %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    setsockopt_return_status = setsockopt(socket_file_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &boolean_option, sizeof(int));
    if (FAILURE == setsockopt_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Setting of options to socket from %s() failed with %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(socket_port_number);
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    

    bind_return_status = bind(socket_file_descriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (FAILURE == bind_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Binding to socket from %s() failed with error %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    listen_return_status = listen(socket_file_descriptor, MAX_LENGTH_PENDING_CONNECTIONS_QUEUE);
    if (FAILURE == listen_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Listening from socket from %s() failed with %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    *socket_file_descriptor_return = socket_file_descriptor;
    return SUCCESS;
}    

static int convert_string_to_integer(char *string_to_convert_into_integer, int *integer_value_return)
{
    char *end_pointer = NULL;
    int integer_number_in_string = 0;

    integer_number_in_string = strtol(string_to_convert_into_integer, &end_pointer, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Convert String to integer number from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(end_pointer == string_to_convert_into_integer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Search integer number in string from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        return FAILURE;
    }

    *integer_value_return = integer_number_in_string;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the thread function

```
#include "error_code.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "erl_interface.h"
#include "ei.h"

struct erlmessage_and_reply_to_erlang_node
{
    ErlMessage *erlmessage;
    ETERM **reply_to_erlang_node;
};

static void release_all_eterm_resources(void *erlmessage_and_reply_to_erlang_node);
static void semaphore_post_cleanup(void *semaphore_id);    

void* query_handler(void *thread_arguments)
{
    ETERM *query_msg_from_erlang_node           = NULL;
    ETERM *message_id                   = NULL;
    ETERM *hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node    = NULL;
    ETERM *set_value_from_erlang_node           = NULL;
    ETERM *set_or_get_data_from_erlang_node         = NULL;
    ETERM *reply_to_erlang_node             = NULL;
    ETERM *i2c_bus_number_eterm             = NULL;
    ETERM *i2c_device_address_eterm             = NULL;

    int status_of_send_erl_message_to_erlang = 0;
    int function_id = 0;    

    unsigned char i2c_bus_number        = 0;
    unsigned char i2c_device_address    = 0;
    int i2c_function_return_status      = {0};
    unsigned char data_to_be_written[400]   = {0};
    unsigned int data_to_be_read[60]    = {0};

    double data_as_double               = 0;
    short int data_as_short_int             = 0;
    unsigned char data_value_as_unsigned_char   = 0;
    double data_value_return_as_double      = 0;
    short int data_value_return_as_short_int    = 0;
    unsigned char data_value_return_as_char     = 0;
    long long int data_value_return_as_long_long_int= 0;

    char eterm_in_form_of_string[15];    

    unsigned char gpio_pin_number = 0;
    unsigned char gpio_port_number = 0;    

    unsigned char channel_number = 0;

    unsigned int start_memory_address = 0;
    unsigned int number_of_bytes_requested_to_read = 0;
    unsigned int number_of_bytes_requested_to_write = 0;

    ErlMessage *erlmessage = (ErlMessage *) thread_arguments;
    struct erlmessage_and_reply_to_erlang_node clean_up_eterms = {
        .erlmessage = erlmessage,
        .reply_to_erlang_node = &reply_to_erlang_node
    };

    pthread_cleanup_push(release_all_eterm_resources, (void *) &clean_up_eterms);

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());    
    query_msg_from_erlang_node = erlmessage->msg;

    function_id                     = ERL_INT_VALUE(erl_element(1, query_msg_from_erlang_node));
    message_id                  = erl_element(2, query_msg_from_erlang_node);
    hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node   = erl_element(3, query_msg_from_erlang_node);    

    i2c_bus_number_eterm = erl_element(2, hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node);
    if(NULL != i2c_bus_number_eterm)
    {
        i2c_bus_number = (unsigned char)ERL_INT_UVALUE(i2c_bus_number_eterm);

        i2c_device_address_eterm = erl_element(3, hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node);
        if(NULL != i2c_device_address_eterm)
        {
            i2c_device_address = (unsigned char)ERL_INT_UVALUE(i2c_device_address_eterm);

            switch(function_id)
            {

                case CHECK_IF_XYZ_IS_PRESENT :    

                    gpio_pin_number = (unsigned char) ERL_INT_UVALUE(erl_element(4, hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node));
                    sem_wait(&i2c_access_semaphore[0]);
                    pthread_cleanup_push(semaphore_post_cleanup, (void *) &i2c_access_semaphore[0]);

                    i2c_function_return_status =
                            check_if_xyz_is_present( i2c_bus_number,
                                         i2c_device_address,
                                         gpio_pin_number,
                                         &data_value_return_as_char );

                    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

                    if(SUCCESS == i2c_function_return_status)
                    {
                        reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ success, ~w, ~w }",
                                erl_mk_int(data_value_return_as_char), message_id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ error, ~i, ~w }",
                                i2c_function_return_status, message_id);
                    }
                    break;    

                case CHECK_IF_ON :

                    gpio_pin_number = (unsigned char) ERL_INT_UVALUE(erl_element(4, hardware_connection_info_from_erlang_node));
                    sem_wait(&i2c_access_semaphore[0]);
                    pthread_cleanup_push(semaphore_post_cleanup, (void *) &i2c_access_semaphore[0]);

                    i2c_function_return_status =
                            check_if_on( i2c_bus_number,
                                             i2c_device_address,
                                             gpio_pin_number,
                                             &data_value_return_as_char );

                    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

                    if(SUCCESS == i2c_function_return_status)
                    {
                        reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ success, ~w, ~w }",
                                erl_mk_int(data_value_return_as_char), message_id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ error, ~i, ~w }",
                                i2c_function_return_status, message_id);
                    }
                    break;

//There are several more cases...

                default :
                    printf("\nError: Search 'function_id': %d from "
                        __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", function_id, __func__, __LINE__);
                    reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ error, command_not_found, ~w }", message_id);

            }    
        }
        else
        {
            reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ error, i2c_device_address_not_received, ~w }", message_id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        reply_to_erlang_node = erl_format("{ error, i2c_bus_number_not_received, ~w }", message_id);
    }

    status_of_send_erl_message_to_erlang = erl_send(
        erlang_node_file_descriptor,
        erlmessage->from,
        reply_to_erlang_node
    );

    if(ERL_SEND_FAILURE == status_of_send_erl_message_to_erlang)
    {
        printf("\nError: Sending message to Erlang node from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        if(ENOMEM == erl_errno)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);    
    return NULL;
}

static void release_all_eterm_resources(void *argument)
{
    ErlMessage *erlmessage = ((struct erlmessage_and_reply_to_erlang_node *) argument)->erlmessage;
    ETERM *reply_to_erlang_node = *(((struct erlmessage_and_reply_to_erlang_node *) argument)->reply_to_erlang_node);

    erl_free_compound(erlmessage->msg);
    erl_free_compound(erlmessage->from);
    erl_free_compound(erlmessage->to);

    erl_free_compound(reply_to_erlang_node);    
    erl_eterm_release();    
    free(erlmessage);
}

static void semaphore_post_cleanup(void *semaphore_id)
{
    sem_post((sem_t *) semaphore_id);
}
```

Comment: Greg, without some code, it's very hard to debug... but I would start with double checking the `if`-`else` statements that handle errors. It could be that errors are freed but that the message is still forwarded to the tasking thread (even though the memory is now invalid). Also, make sure you're using the `erl_free_term` function and not `free`, as some of the memory might be reused as part of an internal buffer.

Comment: Thanks Myst,added the code

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `release_all_eterm_resources` on every path *except* the `ERL_REG_SEND` branch, but the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html) show the constituent compound/term members being freed only *for* `ERL_REG_SEND` messages.

Similarly, the [man pages](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_connect.html#erl_receive_msg) say, eg.

> will return `ERL_TICK` indicating that the tick has been received and responded to, but **no message will be placed in the buffer**

(my emphasis), so releasing msg is unlikely to be correct.

---

It is plausible that those members are simply uninitialized except when they're meaningful for `ERL_(REG_)SEND` messages

You don't use `calloc` or `memset` the message or otherwise initialize them to a known value, so in reality unless the Erlang library zeroes them for you, they could have anything in.

They may end up with whatever values were left by the last message that did set those members (`malloc`/`free` cycles of the same size are likely to stabilize on returning the same pointer every iteration) - which also suggests you could avoid freeing-and-re-allocating the message structure every time round.

> message is ERL_MSG then a thread is created ... is there a better way to do this?

It's generally better to create a thread pool ahead of time. Thread creation itself isn't cheap, so just add the message to a work queue and let your existing pool of threads take care of it.

Comment: "You're calling release_all_eterm_resources on every path except the ERL_REG_SEND branch"; for ERL_REG_SEND branch, release_all_eterm_resources is called in the thread function, where this function is pushed through "pthread_cleanup_push(release_all_eterm_resources, (void *) &clean_up_eterms)" in the beginning of the thread and poped using "pthread_cleanup_pop(1)" at the end of thread which actually calls the function "release_all_eterm_resources". For other branches will free the resources accordingly and try, along with calloc, memset.

Answer (score 0):

Following what is mentioned by Useless, I have tried two changes

Changed malloc to calloc and not calling the release_all_eterm_resources from ERL_TICK and ERL_ERROR, but it still crashes; over night I got 170 times **nodedown** and 9 times **glibc(memory corruption)**.

It is right that no message is being put in the buffer in the case of ERL_TICK. But I doubted that freeing "**erlmessage->msg**"  in case of ERL_TICK might be a linked with this problem.

The changes I made to the code is listed below.

I am planing to do another experiment where I want to replace the thread with process, and observe what happens.

```
#include "error_code.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "erl_interface.h"
#include "ei.h"

#include "i2c_cnode.h"
#include "i2c_cnode_query_handler.h"

static int setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(char *node_name_without_ip,
    char *ip_address, char *magic_cookie, int socket_port_number);
static int initialize_socket_connection(int socket_port_number, int *socket_file_descriptor_return);
static int convert_string_to_integer(char *string_to_convert_into_integer, int *integer_value_return);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *node_name_without_ip                      = NULL;
    char *ip_address_of_card                        = NULL;
    char *magic_cookie                          = NULL;

    int socket_port_number                          = 0;
    int socket_port_number_return                       = 0;
    int status_of_get_socket_port_number                    = FAILURE;

    int semaphore_count                         = 0;
    int semaphore_count_return                      = 0;
    int status_of_get_semaphore_count                   = FAILURE;

    int i = 0; /* used as a loop variable for creation of semaphore */
    int status_of_semaphore_creation                    = FAILURE;
    int socket_file_descriptor                      = 0;
    unsigned char erlang_message_buffer[ERLANG_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE]     = {0};
    int return_status_of_erl_receive_msg                    = ERL_ERROR;
    int return_status_of_erl_close_connection               = 0;

    ErlMessage *erlmessage                          = NULL;
    ErlConnect erlang_node_connection_information               = {
        .ipadr = {0},
        .nodename = {0}
    };
    pthread_t query_handler_thread_id;

    void release_all_eterm_resources()
    {
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->msg);
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->from);
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->to);

        erl_eterm_release();
        free(erlmessage);
    }

    if(NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGS != argc)
    {
        printf("\nError: Arguments validation from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n"
            "Usage : <executable_name> <node_name_without_ip> <ip_address> <cookie> <socket_port_number> <semaphore_count>\n"
            "For example : %s i2c_cnode 10.3.31.127 utl 4022 1 \n"
            "Terminating C node\n\n", __func__, __LINE__, argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    node_name_without_ip = argv[1];

    ip_address_of_card = argv[2];
    magic_cookie = argv[3];

    status_of_get_socket_port_number = convert_string_to_integer(argv[4], &socket_port_number_return);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_socket_port_number)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get Socket port number from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    socket_port_number = socket_port_number_return;

    status_of_get_semaphore_count = convert_string_to_integer(argv[5], &semaphore_count_return);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_semaphore_count)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get Semaphore count from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    semaphore_count = semaphore_count_return;

    if(MAX_COUNT_OF_SEMAPHORE_FOR_I2C_ACCESS < semaphore_count)
    {
        printf("\nError: Too may Semaphores requested from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    socket_file_descriptor = setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(
        node_name_without_ip, ip_address_of_card, magic_cookie, socket_port_number);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT_OF_SEMAPHORE_FOR_I2C_ACCESS; i++)
    {
        status_of_semaphore_creation = sem_init(&i2c_access_semaphore[i], 0, 1);
        if(FAILURE == status_of_semaphore_creation)
        {
            printf("\nError: Create POSIX semaphore from "
                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }


    while(1)
    {
        erlang_node_file_descriptor = erl_accept(socket_file_descriptor, &erlang_node_connection_information);
        if(ERL_ERROR == erlang_node_file_descriptor)
        {
            printf("\nError: Accepting connection from peer node from "
                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
            continue;
        }


        while(1)
        {
            erlmessage = calloc(1,sizeof(ErlMessage));
            if(NULL == erlmessage)
            {
                printf("\nError: Get heap space for ErlMessage from "
                    __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }


            return_status_of_erl_receive_msg = erl_receive_msg(erlang_node_file_descriptor,
                erlang_message_buffer,
                ERLANG_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE,
                erlmessage);


            if(ERL_TICK == return_status_of_erl_receive_msg)
            {
                erl_free_compound(erlmessage->from);
        erl_free_compound(erlmessage->to);
        erl_eterm_release();
        free(erlmessage);
                continue;
            }


            else if(ERL_ERROR == return_status_of_erl_receive_msg)
            {
                printf("\nError: Message receiving from the Erlang node %s, from "
                    __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                    erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                    __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));

                release_all_eterm_resources();
                if(EIO == erl_errno)
                {
                    return_status_of_erl_close_connection = erl_close_connection(
                        erlang_node_file_descriptor);
                    if(SUCCESS != return_status_of_erl_close_connection)
                    {
                        printf("\nError: Closing Erlang file descriptor from "
                            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if((ENOMEM == erl_errno) || (EMSGSIZE == erl_errno))
                {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                switch(erlmessage->type)
                {
                    case ERL_REG_SEND:
                    case ERL_SEND:

                        pthread_create(&query_handler_thread_id, NULL, query_handler, erlmessage);
                        break;

                    case ERL_EXIT:
                        printf("\nError: Message receive from the Erlang node %s, from "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));

                        printf("Received a ERL_EXIT with message: ");
                        erl_print_term(stdout, erlmessage->msg);
                        printf("\n");

                        return_status_of_erl_close_connection = erl_close_connection(erlang_node_file_descriptor);
                        if(SUCCESS != return_status_of_erl_close_connection)
                        {
                            printf("\nError: Close Erlang file descriptor from "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        }
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    case ERL_LINK:
                        printf("\nError : Link Message received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    case ERL_UNLINK:
                        printf("\nError : Unlink Message received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                        break;

                    default:
                        printf("\nError : Unknown Message type received from Erlang node %s in "
                                __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
                                erlang_node_connection_information.nodename,
                                __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
                        release_all_eterm_resources();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


static int setup_connection_to_communicate_with_erlang_node(char *node_name_without_ip,
    char *ip_address, char *magic_cookie, int socket_port_number)
{
    char long_node_name_with_ip[MAX_BYTES_OF_FULL_NODE_NAME]    = {0};
    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX]                    = {0};

    struct in_addr ipv4_address_as_binary_data          = {0};

    int socket_file_descriptor                  = 0;
    int return_status_of_gethostname                = 0;
    int return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit              = 0;
    int return_status_of_erl_publish                = 0;
    int status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor            = FAILURE;


    erl_init(NULL, 0);


    return_status_of_gethostname = gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    if(FAILURE == return_status_of_gethostname)
    {
        printf("\nError: Get hostname from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sprintf(long_node_name_with_ip, "%s@%s", node_name_without_ip, ip_address);


    ipv4_address_as_binary_data.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
    if(BROADCAST_IP_ADDRESS == ipv4_address_as_binary_data.s_addr)
    {
        printf("\nError: Convert of IPv4 dotted notation to binary data from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit = erl_connect_xinit(hostname,node_name_without_ip,
        long_node_name_with_ip, &ipv4_address_as_binary_data, magic_cookie, 0);
    if(return_status_of_erl_connect_xinit <= FAILURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Initialize C Node connection from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(erl_errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor = initialize_socket_connection(socket_port_number,
        &socket_file_descriptor);
    if(FAILURE == status_of_get_socket_file_descriptor)
    {
        printf("\nError: Initialize socket connection from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return_status_of_erl_publish = erl_publish(socket_port_number);
    if(FAILURE == return_status_of_erl_publish)
    {
        printf("\nError: Publish C node to EPMD from " __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nC Node name: %s\n", erl_thisnodename());

    return socket_file_descriptor;
}

static int initialize_socket_connection(int socket_port_number, int *socket_file_descriptor_return)
{
    int socket_file_descriptor      = 0;
    int boolean_option          = 0;

    int setsockopt_return_status        = 0;
    int bind_return_status          = 0;
    int listen_return_status        = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in socket_address   = {0};

    boolean_option = BOOLEAN_OPTION_ENABLE;

    /**
     * A socket is an endpoint for communication. socket() creates a socket according to the
     * IPV4 protocol(AF_INET)  which provides a sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based
     * byte streams(SOCK_STREAM) for communication between two entities. After creation, the
     * socket() returns a descriptor with respect to which further operations can be performed
     */
    socket_file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    if (FAILURE == socket_file_descriptor)
    {
        printf("\nError : Creation of socket from %s() failed with error %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    setsockopt_return_status = setsockopt(socket_file_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &boolean_option, sizeof(int));
    if (FAILURE == setsockopt_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Setting of options to socket from %s() failed with %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(socket_port_number);
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);


    bind_return_status = bind(socket_file_descriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (FAILURE == bind_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Binding to socket from %s() failed with error %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    listen_return_status = listen(socket_file_descriptor, MAX_LENGTH_PENDING_CONNECTIONS_QUEUE);
    if (FAILURE == listen_return_status)
    {
        printf("\nError : Listening from socket from %s() failed with %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    *socket_file_descriptor_return = socket_file_descriptor;
    return SUCCESS;
}


static int convert_string_to_integer(char *string_to_convert_into_integer, int *integer_value_return)
{
    char *end_pointer = NULL;
    int integer_number_in_string = 0;

    integer_number_in_string = strtol(string_to_convert_into_integer, &end_pointer, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Convert String to integer number from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(end_pointer == string_to_convert_into_integer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Search integer number in string from "
            __FILE__ " %s():%d failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        return FAILURE;
    }

    *integer_value_return = integer_number_in_string;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```